# JFreeChart - can't draw graphics like in excel

Tags: java, graphics, jfreechart

I have a problem with draw graphics in JFreeChart, I need to draw a graphic like as in this pic.

[image: excel graphic]

But in java am getting a graphic like this

[image: graphic in java]

is there any possible way to solve this.

**My java code:**

```java
    import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
    import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
    import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
    import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
    import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
    
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    public class MyGraph {
        private static double A=20, R0=-40;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("my graphic");
    
            for (double fi = 0,step = 0.05; fi < 2*Math.PI; fi+=step) addCoordinate(series,fi);
    
            XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory
                    .createXYLineChart("my graphic 14", "x", "y",
                            xyDataset,
                            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                            true, true, true);
            JFrame frame =
                    new JFrame("MinimalStaticChart");
            frame.getContentPane()
                    .add(new ChartPanel(chart));
            frame.setSize(400,300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        private static void addCoordinate(XYSeries series,double fi){
            double ro = Math.cos(fi)-0.5;
            series.add(ro*Math.cos(fi),ro*Math.sin(fi));
            System.out.printf("fi = %f   ro = %f   x = %f   y = %f\n", fi , ro, ro*Math.cos(fi), ro*Math.sin(fi));
        }
    }
```

How you can see in images, form and coordinates the same, but JFreeChart draw graphics not like in excel, how can I draw my Graphic like in excel with java, which methods should I use? (If you can - give examples, please)

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `XYSeries(String)` constructor wich sorts the values by x. You will see it if you would add this after filling your series:

```
for (Object i : series.getItems()) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

So the only thing you need to change is the initialization of `series`:

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("my graphic", false);
```